# Can't read the right channel from MCP3008 in C++ using pigpio

Tags: pi-3, c++, pigpio

I'm trying to use an IR sensor with Raspberry Pi and I have this function to read a specific channel from the ADC MCP3008. When I try to read any other channel but channel 0, it doesn't work. What I mean is, if I call the function to read the channel 2, I can only get the accurate distance from channel 0. Other channels give me gibberish. The problem isn't from the ADC because I have another code that doesn't use SPI and I can read from any channel, I just don't use it because I can only get measurements from lower distances.

---

PS.: I deleted my last post because I asked the wrong question.

```
int ADC_analogRead(int channel){
    int dataADC = 0;
    int handlerSpi = 0;
    char buffer[3]; //bytes to read and send from/to ADC

    if (channel > 7 || channel < 0)
        return -1;

    handlerSpi = spiOpen(0, 100000, 0); // opens SPI channel 0 at 100 kbps, in mode 0

    /* MCU Transmitted Data - page 21 figure 6-1 from datasheet */
    buffer[0] = 1;           // Start bit
    buffer[1] = 128 + channel; // SGL/Diff + Channel to read
    buffer[2] = 0;           // Don't care
    cout << "buffer[1]: " << (unsigned int)buffer[1] << "\n"; 
    spiXfer(handlerSpi, buffer, buffer, 3); // This function sends 3 bytes to ADC from variable buffer and after sending, it read 3 bytes to buffer variable

    /* MCU Received Data */
    /* buffer[0] -> don't cares
       buffer[1] -> first 5 bits are don't cares, 6 bit is null bit and 7/8 are data
       buffer[2] -> all data bits
    */
    dataADC = (((buffer[1] & 3) << 8) | buffer[2]); // binary math to read 10 bits ADC data

    spiClose(handlerSpi);
    return dataADC;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly encode the channel to be read in the command.

```c
buffer[1] = (8+channel)<<4;
```